# Consulta al usar @html.Textboxfor usando ViewBag

Tags: asp.net-mvc, mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, spring-mvc

Solicito de su apoyo tengo la siguiente detalle, estoy intentando que el usuario pueda subir un archivo, para ello hago uso en la vista parcial de lo siguiente que recibe
2 modelos:

```html
@{
    Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM xlsImportadoDoc = ViewBag.xlsimportado;
    @model List<Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.CalificaParcialListaAlumnos_ViewModel>
}
```

Dentro de la vista parcial, hago uso de TextboxFor para solicitar al usuario busque el archivo a subir:

```html
@Html.TextBoxFor(x => xlsImportadoDoc.xls_archivo, new { type = "file", accept = ".xls,.xlsx", size = "4100", @class = "form-control-file", onchange = "return ValidaArchivoExcel();" })
```

Pero me marca un error y en el navegador depurando a detalle esto indica:
ReferenceError: "x" is not defined Para llamar a la vista parcial previa, en la acción del controlador que llamara a la vista parcial lleno un ViewBag usando un modelo y a la ves les asigno valores a 2 campos con datos de lo contrario
me marca problema por valores null:

```
AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM xlsBuscado = new AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM();
            xlsBuscado.xls_calificacion = "0.0";
            xlsBuscado.xls_archivo = "";
            ViewBag.xlsimportado = xlsBuscado;
```

El problema creo que radica aquí en la línea del html.textboxfor donde quiero asignar el nombre al textboxfor, lo ideal es usar x=>x.xls_archivo pero como comento estoy usando un viewbag y no puedo hacerlo de esta manera:

x => xlsImportadoDoc.xls_archivo Estoy intentando hacer uso del dato que se almacenara en xlsImportadoDoc.xls_archivo para guardarlo en servidor, y como verán uso 2 modelos en la vista uno de tipo list y otro es simple para un registro... de ahí
que intente hacerlo usando con el ViewBag.xlsimportado.... de que forma haciendo uso del texboxfor puedo solucionar... Muchas gracias amigos...

```html
@{
    Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.AgilizaCaptura_Parcial_VM xlsImportadoDoc = ViewBag.xlsimportado;
    @model List<Calificaciones.Models.ViewModels.CalificaParcialListaAlumnos_ViewModel>
}

<style>
    table.table-striped {
        /* border-collapse: collapse;*/
        border: none;
    }

    td.celda_sin {
        padding: 0;
    }

    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > td,
    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(odd) > th {
        background-color: #fff;
    }

    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > td,
    .table-striped > tbody > tr:nth-child(even) > th {
        background-color: #ECECEC;
    }

    .table-striped > thead > tr > th {
        background-color: #eee;
    }
</style>

<div class="card card-default">
    <div class="card-body">
        <div class="row mb-1">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-6  py-1">
                <h4>Subir archivo de excel y aplicar calificación</h4>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-1 br py-2">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-5 py-1">
                <h4>Calificación para todo el grupo</h4>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div class="row mb-1">
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-7 br  py-1  ">
                @*@Html.TextBoxFor(x => xlsImportadoDoc.xls_archivo, new { type = "file", accept = ".xls,.xlsx", size = "4100", @class = "form-control-file", onchange = "return VerificarArchivoCargado();" })*@
                <div class="input-group">
                    <label class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-success">
                            <i class='fas fa-upload text-white'></i> <input type="file" accept=".xls,.xlsx" , style="display: none;" id="fileUpload">
                        </span>
                    </label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" style="width:auto;" id="txtUploadFile" readonly>
                    <label class="input-group-btn">
                        <span class="btn btn-primary">
                            Aplicar a parcial <input type="button" style="display: none;" id="btnUpload" value="Upload File">
                        </span>
                    </label>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-2 py-1">
                @Html.TextBox(xlsImportadoDoc.xls_calificacion, "0.0", new { @tabindex = "1", @required = "true", @class = "form-control text-bold text-center", maxlength = 4, onkeypress = "return checkNotas(event);", onKeyUP = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-12 col-lg-3 py-1">
                <a href="@Url.Action("DescargaLista", "Calificaciones", new { cr_cic_esc = Model[0].cr_cic_esc, cr_per_imp = Model[0].cr_per_imp, cr_cve_ent = Model[0].cr_cve_ent, cr_cve_car = Model[0].cr_cve_car, cr_cve_gpo = Model[0].cr_cve_gpo, cr_cve_mat = Model[0].cr_cve_mat, cr_cve_maes = Model[0].cr_rpe, cr_materia = Model[0].cr_nombre_materia, cr_docente = Model[0].cr_nombre_maes, cr_nom_carrera = Model[0].cr_nombre_carrera })" class="mb-1 btn btn-success" title="Clic para aplicar calificación a todo el grupo">  <i class='fas fa-bolt text-white'></i> Aplicar a grupo</a>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div><!-- END card-->

<table class="table-striped table-responsive-md table-hover">
    <thead>
        <tr class="text-bold bg-primary-light">
            <td width="15%">Clave única</td>
            <td width="25%">Apellido paterno</td>
            <td width="25%">Apellido materno</td>
            <td width="25%">Nombre (s)</td>
            <td width="10%" class="text-center">Calificación</td>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    @for (int i = 0; i < Model.Count; i++)
    {
        <tr>
            <td class="celda_sin">
                @Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_id", Model[i].cr_id, new { @hidden = "true" })
                @*@Html.Label("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].rango", Model[i].rango, new { @class = "text-bold text-center" })*@
                @Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_nolista", Model[i].cr_nolista, new { @hidden = "true" })

                @Html.Label("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_cve_unica", Model[i].cr_cve_unica, new { @class = "text-center" })
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_cve_unica", Model[i].cr_cve_unica, new { @tabindex = "1", @required = "true" })*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_cve_unica", Model[i].cr_cve_unica, new { @required = "true", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true", })*@

            </td>
            <td class="celda_sin">
                @Html.Label("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_apaterno", Model[i].cr_apaterno, new { @class = "text-center" })
                @Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_apaterno", Model[i].cr_apaterno, new { @hidden = "true" })
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_apaterno", Model[i].cr_apaterno, new { @tabindex = "2", @required = "true" })*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_apaterno", Model[i].cr_apaterno, new { @required = "true", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_apaterno", Model[i].cr_apaterno + " " + Model[i].cr_amaterno + " " + Model[i].cr_nombres, new { @tabindex = "2", @required = "true", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
            </td>
            <td class="celda_sin">
                @Html.Label("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_amaterno", Model[i].cr_amaterno, new { @class = "text-center" })
                @Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_amaterno", Model[i].cr_amaterno, new { @hidden = "true" })
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_amaterno", Model[i].cr_amaterno, new { @tabindex = "3", @required = "true" })*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_amaterno", Model[i].cr_amaterno, new { @required = "true", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
            </td>
            <td class="celda_sin">
                @Html.Label("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_nombres", Model[i].cr_nombres, new { @class = "text-center" })
                @Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_nombres", Model[i].cr_nombres, new { @hidden = "true" })
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_nombres", Model[i].cr_nombres, new { @tabindex = "4", @required = "true" })*@
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_nombres", Model[i].cr_nombres, new { @required = "true", @class = "form-control", @readonly = "true" })*@
            </td>
            <td class="celda_sin">
                @Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].cr_calificacion", Model[i].cr_calificacion, new { @tabindex = "1", @required = "true", @class = "form-control text-bold text-center", maxlength = 4, onkeypress = "return checkNotas(event);", onKeyUP = "this.value=this.value.toUpperCase();" })
                @*@Html.TextBox("CalificaParcial[" + @i + "].horas", Model[i].horas, new { @tabindex = "3", @type = "number", @min = "8", @max = "20", @required = "true" })*@
            </td>
        </tr>
    }
</table>


@section Scripts
{
    <script src="~/Scripts/calificaciones/jsValidaArchivo.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        $(document).ready(function () {
            debugger;
            $('#btnUpload').click(function () {
                debugger;
                if (window.FormData !== undefined) {
                    var fileUpload = $('#fileUpload').get(0);
                    var files = fileUpload.files;

                    var fileData = new FormData();

                    for (var i = 0; i < files.length; i++) {
                        fileData.append(files[i].name, files[i]);
                    }
                    $.ajax({
                        url: '/Captura/InmportarExcel',
                        type: "POST",
                        contentType: false,
                        processData: false,
                        data: fileData,
                        success: function (result) {
                            if (result.success) {
                                dataTable.ajax.reload();

                                $.notify(result.message, {
                                    globalPosition: "top center",
                                    className: "success"
                                })

                            }
                        }
                    });
                } else {
                    $.notify("File is not supported.");
                }
            });



        });

        $(function () {
            $(document).on('change', ':file', function () {
                var input = $(this),
                    numFiles = input.get(0).files ? input.get(0).files.length : 1,
                    label = input.val().replace(/\\/g, '/').replace(/.*\//, '');
                input.trigger('fileselect', [numFiles, label]);
            });

            // We can watch for our custom `fileselect` event like this
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(':file').on('fileselect', function (event, numFiles, label) {

                    var input = $(this).parents('.input-group').find(':text'),
                        log = numFiles > 1 ? numFiles + ' files selected' : label;

                    if (input.length) {
                        input.val(log);
                    } else {
                        if (log) alert(log);
                    }

                });
            });

        });


    </script>

}
```

Comment: No ocupes `Html.TextBoxFor`, usa simplemente un `<input type="file" ..`

Comment: Saludos amigo, lo inicie con input type="file"... pero tengo un detalle que al estar dentro de una vista parcial, el botón de examinar abre la ventana de dialogo y selecciono el archivo pero no lo deposita en text para ver el archivo, y el botón de Importar al dar clic no llama la función clic para llamar al método con su acción... Al final de la cuestión he colocado el código completo de la vista

Answer (score 0):

Creo que no le estas pasando los parámetros correctos a Html.TextBoxFor, podes probar en pasarlo por HtmlRaw.TextBoxFor() y los parámetros sin indicar puntualmente a que corresponde cada uno, no veo en realidad como está hecho el constructor como para ver que parámetros usa

Comment: Bienvenido al sitio, te sugiero revisar [answer], saludos.